# How can I get weapons for 3rd spec?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Months ago I played my rogue and got legendaries for outlaw and sub specs.

I return now to WoW and wanted to try out assassination, but I never got my assassination legendary weapons.

The two legendary weapons I have only work in sub and outlaw specs.

How can I get weapons so I can play assassin spec in 8.0 if I never got the legendaries? I forget how to get the weapons in the first place. Is there a quest line I can do to get them? Or do I have to wait for BFA to get some random weapon drops that work with the spec/ or use low level weapons?

Answer (score 1):

Even though 8.0 has just come up, unlocking the legendary weapons will always be available. Note, the mage tower appearances will not.

[Link](http://www.wowhead.com/acquiring-the-kingslayers-assassination-rogue-artifact).

[here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JC9gE4SRtIU&t=0s&index=26&list=PLar4nrXN3ddp3UabktJ2r8ndvpwVl3OZA)

best of luck!

edit: You must be level 102 to get your 2nd and 3rd legendary weapon. Are you level 102+?

Comment: where can i start the quest for my 3rd spec legendary? i went to my rogue HQ or whatever ( srry havnt played in 11 months ) and there were no quests to start

Comment: @user3822544 I am not 100% certain, I unfortunately do not have a rogue but all 3 of my legendary started from a quest. From the video link, it appears the quest is started in Dalaran that approaches you, maybe try walking around dalaran?

Comment: ya im 110. ill look around dalaran some more or do some googling. my friend said it was impossible but it sounds like i may just have to search harder cause the quest may be low level and not appearing on my map.

Comment: they also said that i could get a lvl 210 EPIC weapon from darkshore daily quests? is that true? are they better then the legendaries?

Comment: @user3822544 Ah that is true, make sure you have `show low level quests` activated on your mini map.  Yes, the BfA darkshore events will drop 210 with a chance of war/titan forge. Depending on their stats, yes they could be better.

Comment: They're not legendaries, they're artifacts. The rogue quest starts in the order hall (like for most classes) and you probably need to be level 104.

Comment: It might be level 105, actually. I got all three artifact weapons, but my rogue is 110 and I don't recall exactly what level I was offered the third quest. If you're at least 105 and don't see someone following you around Dalaran with a quest, run downstairs to the class hall and you should be able to find it.